# How to change a radio button's cell color based on which radio button is selected

Tags: excel, radio-button, cell, conditional-formatting

I'm building a checklist in excel, but am having trouble figuring out how to use Conditional Formatting for my
radio button cells. For instance, here you see 2 cells, B7 and C7, each containing a radio button.

[image: 1]

I need the default cell color to be red for both of them upon opening the file. But let's say a user clicks the "Breakers" button, 
it's cell (B7) should turn green, and the "Fuses" cell should turn white. If fuses is clicked, it turns green and breakers turns white.

Should I be using a formula within "Conditional Formatting" to accomplish this? Hopefully I'm describing the problem correctly, thanks a ton for your help!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Link your Radio Button to a cell.

So if the first radio button is checked the linked cell will have value 1, if the second is checked, the cell value is to.

So now you do the conditional formatting in both cells like this:

"Use a formula to determine which cells to format"
  and put "The linked cell reference"=1

and the same for the other cell but comparing with value 2.

Sorry if I am not very clear, I tried to post images but I am not allowed since I have no reputation here.